# Replace cartridge in Seaford basin mono mixer tap

Tags: faucet, replacement, cartridge

I have this tap 
https://www.screwfix.com/p/seaford-basin-mono-mixer-tap-with-pop-up-waste/853fv

I have got the cap off and unscrewed the screw underneath - but what do I do next??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to tap, tap, pull, tap until the handle breaks free of the valve stem. Then with a strap wrench, remove that chrome collar. That will expose the valve stem. unscrew it and take it to your home store or a plumbing supply store for a replacement. Good luck and stay safe out there.